# postgres many to one unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm curious if there is a way to write a unique constraint to support the following situation.

Suppose I have table `table1` with facts about a user, with four columns:

- `user_id`: unique id for user
- `source`: where the detail came from
- `d1`: dimension 1 of the fact
- `d2`: dimension 2 of the fact

The following is an example of data in this table:

```
| row_id | user_id | source | d1     | d2      |
|--------|---------|--------|--------|---------|
| 1      | aaa111  | foo    | bar    | 123     |
| 2      | aaa111  | foo    | baz    | 'horse' |
| 3      | aaa111  | scrog  | bar    | 123     |
| 4      | bbb222  | foo    | goober | 456     |
```

Currently, a unique constraint exists on `source + d1 + d2`.  This is good, because it allows the **same user** to have duplicates of `(d1,d2)`, as long as they have a different `source`.
Rows #1 and #3 demonstrate this for user `aaa111`.

However, this constraint does not prevent the following row from getting added...

```
| row_id | user_id | source | d1     | d2      |
|--------|---------|--------|--------|---------|
| 1      | aaa111  | foo    | bar    | 123     |
| 2      | aaa111  | foo    | baz    | 'horse' |
| 3      | aaa111  | scrog  | bar    | 123     |
| 4      | bbb222  | foo    | goober | 456     |
| 5      | bbb222  | turnip | baz    | 'horse' |  <---- allowed new row
```

...because `source` is different for rows #2 and #5.

I would like to add a unique constraint where the combination of `(d1,d2)` may only exist for a **single** `user_id`.

Said another way, a single user can have as many unique `(source, d1, d2)` combinations as needed, but cannot share `(d1,d2)` with another `user_id`.

Is this data model fundamentally flawed to support this constraint?  or is there a unique constraint that might help enforce this?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a conditional-constraint, you can use a trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE that raise exception when violate the constraint:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user_combination() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE
  vCheckUser INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO vCheckUser user_id
  FROM table1 
  WHERE d1 = NEW.d1 
    AND d2 = NEW.d2 
    AND user_id <> NEW.user_id;

  IF vCheckUser IS NOT NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'User % have already d1=% and d2=%',vCheckUser,NEW.d1, NEW.d2;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
  language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_combination BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_user_combination();
```

This prevent insert or update additional user for the same d1 and d2.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thanks a bunch!